# Injection failed with Jersey, Weld, and DeltaSpike

Tags: jersey, cdi, weld, deltaspike

I'm working on a JAX-RS project.
I uses Jersey, Weld, and DeltaSpike.

```java
@Path("test")
public class TestResource {

    @GET
    @Path("now")
    public String now() {
        return new Date().toString();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("myProperty")
    public String myProprety() {

        return myProperty;
    }

    @Inject
    @ConfigProperty(name = "my.proprety")
    private String myProperty;
}
```

When I trying to `GET /test/myProperty`, I got.

```
org.glassfish.hk2.api.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: There was no object available for injection at
```

Answer (score 2):

I have to add two more dependencies to make this work.

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers.glassfish</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-gf-cdi</artifactId>
    <version>2.14</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.transaction-api</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I doubt this is the root of the issue.  How are you deploying to glassfish?

Comment: I'm not targeting GF. My war is for Apache Tomcat.

Answer (score 0):

Make the resource a ManagedBean (or cdi Singleton) like that:

```java
@Path("test")
@ManagedBean
public class TestResource {
    ....
```